# Body of AIML <condition> loop fails to execute in Pandorabots

Tags: loops, dictionary, global-variables, aiml, pandorabots

I'm trying to loop through a list using AIML in [Pandorabots](https://home.pandorabots.com), with [the standard library](https://github.com/pandorabots/aiml-utilities/blob/master/lib/aimlstandardlibrary.aiml), via MS Edge on an up-to-date Windows 11.

All of the following code occurs within the same `<think>` tags.

There's another loop immediately prior to this one. These two loops are functionally identical. Each loop references a different map of zero-based indices to predicate names, in order to set all the predicate values to "unknown".

The only difference is the two map files; the only difference between them is case and (trivial) string length, and they both work in other contexts:

`[["0", "HI"], ["1", "BY"], ["2", "OK"], [ ... ]]` and `[["0", "hello"], ["1", "byenow"], ["2", "okay"], [ ... ]]`

So the first loop works, but then this one does apparently nothing:

```
<set var="i">0</set>
<set var="allreset">FALSE</set>
<condition var="allreset" value="FALSE">

    <!-- reset predicate -->
    <set><name><map name="thingsdict"><get var="i" /></map></name>
        unknown
    </set>

    <!-- increment and check for OOR -->
    <set var="i"><map name="successor"><get var="i" /></map></set>
    <set var="allreset">
        <srai>XEQ <map name="thingsdict"><get var="i" /></map> XS unknown</srai>
    </set>
    <loop />
</condition>
```

Here's the previous loop, the one that works correctly:

```
<set var="i">0</set>
<set var="allreset">FALSE</set>
<condition var="allreset" value="FALSE">

    <!-- reset predicate -->
    <set><name><map name="otherthingsdict"><get var="i" /></map></name>
        unknown
    </set>

    <!-- increment and check for OOR -->
    <set var="i"><map name="successor"><get var="i" /></map></set>
    <set var="allreset">
        <srai>XEQ <map name="otherthingsdict"><get var="i" /></map> XS unknown</srai>
    </set>
    <loop />
</condition>
```

Literally identical, no?

EDIT: Full category (with think tags commented out for debug):

```
<category>
    <pattern>5</pattern>
    <template>
        Starting over...
        <br/><br/>
        <!--<think>-->
            <set name="mode">unknown</set>
            <set name="score">unknown</set>
            <set name="ties">unknown</set>
            <set name="tiecount">unknown</set>
            
            <!-- loop through first map of related predicates -->
            <set var="i">0</set>
            <set var="allreset">FALSE</set>
            <condition var="allreset" value="FALSE">
                <map name="thingsdict"><get var="i" /></map>
                <set><name><map name="thingsdict"><get var="i" /></map></name>
                    unknown
                </set>
                <set var="i"><map name="successor"><get var="i" /></map></set>
                <set var="allreset">
                    <srai>XEQ <map name="thingsdict"><get var="i" /></map> XS unknown</srai>
                </set>
                <loop />
            </condition>
            
            <!-- loop through other related predicates -->
            <set var="i">0</set>
            <set var="allreset">FALSE</set>
            <condition var="allreset" value="FALSE">
                <map name="otherthingsdict"><get var="i" /></map>
                <set><name><map name="otherthingsdict"><get var="i" /></map></name>
                    unknown
                </set>
                <set var="i"><map name="successor"><get var="i" /></map></set>
                <set var="allreset">
                    <srai>XEQ <map name="otherthingsdict"><get var="i" /></map> XS unknown</srai>
                </set>
                <loop />
            </condition>
        <!--</think>-->
        All values erased!
        <br/><br/>
        <srai>HI</srai>
    </template>
</category>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If the only thing that is different is the map, could you at least post a sample of each map? What happens if you copy "otherthingsdict" to "thingsdict"? Does that now make your loop work?

Comment: The only difference between them is case, and they both work in other contexts. `[["0", "HI"], ["1", "BY"], ["2", "OK"], [ ... ]]` and 
`[["0", "hello"], ["1", "byenow"], ["2", "okay"], [ ... ]]`
The problem seems to be with the condition loops. For example, if I comment out the think tags and place a `<map name="thingsindex"><get var="i" /></map>` (or `"otherthingsindex"`) just before either condition tag, then it will print correctly to the user. But not if it's inside the condition tags. In addition to this, the contents of only the latter condition tags appear not to execute at all.

Comment: This works fine for me. I tried it in a blank bot. Could you post the full category please rather than just the loop part.

Comment: Done! @SteveWorswick

Comment: This works fine for me and all the predicates get set to "unknown". Are you also wanting the user to see a display of them all being reset?

Comment: No, that's just for this debug. I do suspect some backend bug somewhere at Pandorabots. A few times now I have had to refresh the portal in order to use the new functionality in a newly saved file. This is all in MS Edge on an up-to-date Windows 11.

Comment: It worked fine for me on Pandorabots using a blank bot. If you want to post your full maps, I could take another look but all looks good to me.

Comment: I found a solution to the main problem: my `<srai>` was matching one of my own patterns with the predicate name and wildcards. I'm still not sure why nothing inside either condition will print to the user, but fortunately that isn't essential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any `<loop/>` tag must occur within `<li>` tags. Be sure to include a set of `<li>` tags without a `<loop/>` element as well; these can be empty or not.